# Martingale property of a counting process subtracting its compensator

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I shall show that for a point process (counting process) $\Phi((0,t])=\sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbf{1}_{\lbrace T_n \leq t \rbrace}$,
\begin{align*}
M_t = \Phi((0,t]) - \int_{0}^{t} \mathbf{1}_{\lbrace s < T_{\infty}\rbrace} \lambda (X_{s}) ds,
\end{align*}
is for all $t \geq 0$ a $\lbrace \mathcal{F}_t \rbrace$-martingale. The $T_1,T_2, \dots$ are jump times, $\int_{0}^{t} \mathbf{1}_{\lbrace s < T_{\infty}\rbrace} \lambda (X_{s}) ds $ the compensator of a point process and $X_s$ the value of a stochastic process $(X_t)$ at time $s$.

I've already shown $\mathbb{E}[|M_t|]< \infty$. Now I have to show the martingale property $E [M_s \mid \mathcal{F}_t] = M_t $ for all $s < t$ with $s,t \geq 0$ but I have problems to show it. I would be very thankful for your help.

Comment: Do you have any kind of independence and/or stationarity in the inter arrival times ($T_i - T_{i-1}$)?

Comment: The inter arrival times $T_n-T_{n-1}$ are independent, but the jump times $T_1,T_2, \dots$ are dependent in the sense, that $\mathbb{P}(T_1<T<2< \dots <T_n)=1$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.

Comment: Can anyone give me at least one hint? I think it should be a common transformation used in working with martingales